# Create matplotlib polygon patch using image mask

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, polygon, mask

I have an image and a series of polygon masks...[image]

**How can I create polygon patches that trace the mask outlines for over plotting on the image?**

Here's what I want as the final figure.

[image]

Comment: Cant you just plot the polygons with no fill and only border?

Comment: @user8408080 Maybe he needs to extract the polygon masks from some third party tool?

Comment: You can use scikit-image to [find the contours](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.find_contours).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen you're right; because of the color, I immediately thought about `matplotlib`. In that case, OP has to specify what he means with "polygon patches". Edge detection will give a rasterized image, which does not seem to be wanted