# How to draw a Polygon Patch from a bitmask

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib I show an image using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`. I also know how to draw a **filled** [Polygon](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html). One of the required arguments is `xy` a numpy array of shape (N, 2) where each of the N rows represents the x-y co-ordinates of a polygon point.

Now, a filled polygon rendered onto an image can also be represented by a bitmask (with the same height and width as the image), with 1s for fill, and 0s otherwise.

My question is, if I have a bitmask rather than polygon points, is there a way to draw a filled Polygon in matplotlib directly from that? And I mean in the general case where the bitmask may have more than one contiguous blob, or it may have holes:

[image]

It doesn't have to be a Polygon, but it should still be an [Artist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/artist_api.html) of some sort.

Note: There is this similar question [Create matplotlib polygon patch using image mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543062/create-matplotlib-polygon-patch-using-image-mask) but it has not been satisfactorily answered. Finding contours is an idea, but I want to know if there is something more direct in matplotlib.

Comment: This is all quite unclear and abstract. Can you expand your question ([mcve]) to include an example image and bitmask?

Comment: @Alex I've edited my question to be clearer. Perhaps I can come back later and add examples if it still hasn't been answered.

Comment: Well, an `AxesImage` is also an artist, so if it doesn't need to be a Polygon you can just overlay the bitmask as another image over your image.

Comment: @Stef hmm okay, that makes sense, I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overlay the bitmask as a another `AxesImage` over your image by converting the bitmask into an RGBA image (`overlay` in the example):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
import numpy as np

with get_sample_data("grace_hopper.jpg") as file:
    img = plt.imread(file)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

bitmask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
bitmask[500:580, 100:400] = 1
ax1.imshow(bitmask, cmap='gray')
ax1.set_title('Bitmask')

# 50 % opaque overlay
overlay = np.dstack((np.full(bitmask.shape + (3,), [255, 255, 0], dtype=np.uint8),
                     bitmask * 128))
ax2.imshow(img)
ax2.imshow(overlay)
ax2.set_title('Overlayed Bitmask')
```

[image]